# Making SegmentedButton to cover the full avaliable space in FieldSet using SenchaTouch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

If you look at the image below, I have an segment button which is placed on top of a FieldSet. I want the segmented button to cover the full space available in the FieldSet. I have used the following layout for the SegmentedButton. Help me to fix this.

```
 var btn = new Ext.SegmentedButton({
         layout: {
            type : 'hbox',
            pack : 'center',
            align: 'stretchmax'
        },
        allowMultiple: false,
        items: [
            {
               text: 'Switch 1',
                widht:'100%',
               labelWidth : '100%',
                modal: true,
                pressed: true
            },
            {
                text   : 'Switch 2',
                widht:'100%',
                labelWidth :'100%',
                modal: true
            }
        ]
    });
```

### [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `widht` instead of `width` and you need to set it to 50% not 100%

```
var btn = new Ext.SegmentedButton({
     layout: {
        type : 'hbox',
        pack : 'center',
        align: 'stretchmax'
    },

    allowMultiple: false,
    items: [
        {
           text: 'Switch 1',
            width:'50%',
           labelWidth : '100%',
            modal: true,
            pressed: true
        },
        {
            text   : 'Switch 2',
            width:'50%',
            labelWidth :'100%',
            modal: true
        }
    ]
});
```

live example at: http://jsfiddle.net/p5K4q/31/